# ViewController screen to download database before launch application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, splash-screen

I used the storyboard to create my application, where the initial View is an `TabBarController`.

But the first time the application starts I download the database (4Mb). So, my splash screen is displayed until the download is over, because the download is done in AppDelegate. I would like to change it and display a View to the user indicating that a download is being done, not to get the impression that the application crashed.

I tried this in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` but doesn't work:

```
LoadViewController *loadView = [[LoadViewController alloc] init];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[self.window addSubview:[loadView view]];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the networking code in AppDelegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this will meet your needs but I used [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) to handle some display while uploading data to a server, maybe you could do something like the same with your download of the database.

```
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:[self view]];
[[self view] addSubview:HUD];
HUD.dimBackground = YES;
HUD.delegate = self;
[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(taskToDownloadDatabase) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

This would allow you to show the user some progress that something is happening and when the database is fully downloaded initialize your view.

Answer (score 0):

Why not download the database outside the appDelegate, then share it with the appdelegate? Or Perhaps do:

```
[self performSelector@selector(downloadDatabase) afterDelay:1...];
```

so the view loads first?

Comment: Because I need all database before lauching application. And while they are still downloading, I want to indicate to the user that a download is in progress to not appear that the application crashed.